# Receiving Name error: name "arms" is not defined error

Tags: python, replit

I am being asked to create a workout based on user inputted difficulty and body area. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong with what seems to be a simple code. I am very new to coding and have been asked to only use concepts that have been taught.

Concept(s) to Apply:

1. Nested `if/elif/else`
2. `int()`
3. `input()`
4. Variables
5. `print()`

Currently trying to ask the user to input an exercise type and use the input to output a full workout. The print output is a placeholder for the actual output while trying to figure out what the error is and how to fix it.

```py
exercise_type = input("Enter the type of exercise: ")

if exercise_type == arms:
  print("arms")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input function outputs a string, meaning that if you type `arms` when you run the script,the value of `exercise_type` is `"arms"`.

Therefore, your code should be :

```py
exercise_type = input("Enter the type of exercise: ")

if exercise_type == "arms": print("arms")
else : print("Exercise not recognized")
```

In your version, `arms` refers to a variable with that name which does not exist. (Which explains the error)

Comment: thank you so much I was pulling my hair over this and I knew it was something simple. If i wanted it to have multiple conditions to print a specific workout (difficulty level) I would do something like if exercise_type == "arms" and difficulty_level ==x : print("y") ? after defining the difficulty_level variable of course.

Comment: Exactly ! Just be careful that input ALWAYS returns a string so if you ask for an integer like "What is your difficulty ? (1 to 5)" the value will never be `1` or `5` but `"1"` or `"5"`